# how can i build a card shuffling method in java for cards to go in a specific order?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

the cards have to alternate like top half and bottom half in this order till it goes through a 52 card deck. Each deck half has 26 cards they go in the following order:

```
top1, bottom1, top2, bottom2, top3, bottom3, top4, bottom 4, ..., top n, bottom n
```

I was thinking of doing this: `Card[] topHalf= new Card[cards.length/2];`

```
public void shuffle() {
    int index = 0;

    for (int suit = 0; suit <= 1; suit++) {
        for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
            cards[index] = new Card(value, suit);
            index++;
        }
    }
    Card[] botHalf= new Card[(cards.length+26)/2];

    int index2 = 0;

    for (int suit = 2; suit <= 3; suit++) {
        for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
            cards[index] = new Card(value, suit);
            index2++;

        }
        for (int row = 0; row < cards.length; row++){

            row++;

            Card [] temp = new Card[( topHalf.length)+botHalf.length];
        //cards[row]= cards[index];
    }
```

Comment: please clarify; it isn't shuffling if you are putting the card in a specific order

Comment: @ninja I think the phrase we’re looking for is “riffle shuffle.”

Comment: if he is looking for rifle shuffle or "monkey shuffle" as the java developers put it there is already a method in the Collections API for this.

Comment: @jleedev: I thought so too, but the top1,bottom1 permutation doesn't make sense then. If so that would be left1,right1,left2,left2,...oh...

Comment: im a total noob to java and im trying really hard. I study java like 8 to 12 hours a day in class and its driving me nuts sometimes. My book collection in java books is huge now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the cards in a Sorted Map using the order in which they are to appear as a key. The Sorted Map will do the sorting for you. You can then iterate through them all in order:

```
SortedMap map = new SortedMap();

map.put(1, "top1");
map.put(2, "bottom1");
map.put(3, "top2");
...
...
...
Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   Object key = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(" card :" + map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: ...apart from the fact that your sorting won't work, since you're using Strings as the key instead of Integers.  Therefore 10 will appear in between 1 and 2.  Common mistake. Also, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN: Change the keys from strings to integers and never look a gift horse in the mouth. It fits his description of the problem and I don't seen anyone else typing in actual code.

Comment: i never studied maps yet. I am still trying to figure this out. I feel so dumb

Comment: @JavaProgrammer: Firstly, You're not dumb. Everyone has a first time in trying new things. Maps are just 1-1 associative key structures. Check the link for more info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Sorry, sometimes I'm too harsh with words when I point out flaws in people's code. FYI, the question is not about sorting the cards, but about taking an already-sorted deck and shuffling them using a specific technique.  I have typed some actual code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, it sounds like the shuffle you want would arrange the numbers

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

as

`1 8 2 7 3 6 4 5`.

The most efficient way to do this is to create a new array, since swapping elements around in-place isn't easy and won't be fast.  The key observation in this pattern is that every even element (starting with index 0, so the first element is even) counts upwards from the start of the deck, and odd element counts backwards from the end of the deck.

Using this information, we can loop over the new array, copying in the values from a specific index the original array, based upon whether the current index is odd or even.  If the current index in our new array is called `i`, then

- If `i` is even, then the element we want is at index `i/2`
- If `i` is odd, then the element is at index `array.length - (i+1)/2` (the `+1` is to round up to the nearest even number)

Here is the code:

```
public static Card[] rifleShuffle(Card[] deck) {
    Card[] newDeck = new Card[deck.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < newDeck.length; i++) {
        // Check whether current index is odd or even by using mod 2
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            newDeck[i] = deck[i / 2];
        } else {
            newDeck[i] = deck[deck.length - ((i + 1) / 2)];
        }
    }

    return newDeck;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Card[] deck1 = new Card[52];

    int i = 0;
    for (int suite = 0; suite < 4; suite++) {
        for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {
            deck1[i++] = new Card(value, suite);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Before shuffling: " + Arrays.toString(deck1));

    Card[] deck2 = rifleShuffle(deck1);

    System.out.println("After shuffling:  " + Arrays.toString(deck2));
}
```